# Floating action button anchor

Tags: java, android, material-design

I need to anchor floating action button in android, but have the trouble:
fab will be in navigationview
Here is my activity_main layout.
It includes navigation drawer.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <include
        layout="@layout/nav_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Navigation drawer layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/clDrawer"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer_view"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/anav_header"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary2"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/colorIcon"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/colorIcon"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/navFAB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/plus_icon"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorIcon"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/headerLayout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And my `anav_header` for navigation view contains only the few text view.
I need fab to be anchored to the botom of the header, right between header and main content of ND. 
The problem is `layout_anchor` works only if header and nav view are in the same layout. if i use navigationview property `headerLayout` , `layout_anchor` doesnt work. Also if i use `NavigationView.addHeaderView()`, it doesnt work too.
If i include header in navigation view layout by that way

```
<include
        layout="@layout/anav_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

it works, BUT header and navigation view move like different parts. And i need them to act like one navigation drawer.
[I need navigation drawer to lookes smth like that.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSS5s.png)

Comment: just put your FloatingActionButton code in your header layout xml not in main content

Comment: @Pavan, yeh, but fab will be always at the bottom of the header, and never will lay between header and main content layouts.

Comment: @TooLazy have you found a way to put FAB between header and menu in `NavigationView`?

Answer (score 0):

I have found my way.
First i've removed `NavigationView` and replaced it with `drawer_header.xml` with is simple `LinearLayout` with header image, and with drawer_list just after it with is a `LinearLayout` too with static menu items.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary2">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                 android:id="@+id/navView"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:background="@color/colorPrimary2"
                 app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
                 app:itemIconTint="@color/colorIcon"
                 app:itemTextColor="@color/colorIcon"
                 app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer_view" />-->
            <include
                layout="@layout/drawer_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"/>
            <include
                layout="@layout/layout_drawer_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/navFAB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/plus_icon"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorIcon"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/headerLayout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

So, i made header and menu as `LinearLayout`, otherwise they both have scrolled, but i need em to scroll together. To add elements in header or menu you can use `addView(View v)`.